# Total expected time

Tags: probability

The first task has a probability of success of $p$, $0 < p < 1$. Assume each attempt are independent. After the first task is completed, the second task (trials also independent) has a probability of success of $p/k$ where $k$ is the number of trials to complete the first task.

Find $E(T)$ where $T$ is the total time to complete both tasks.

So let $T_1$ be the time to complete the first task and $T_2$ be the time to complete the second task.

So far:

$$T_1\sim\mathrm{Geo}(p) \text{ and } T_2\sim\mathrm{Geo}\left(\frac p k\right)$$

$$E(T)=E(T_1)+E(T_2\mid T_1)$$

$$P(T_2=j\mid T_1=k)=\frac{P(T_2, T_1=k)}{P(T_1=k)} = \frac{(\frac{p}{k})(1-\frac p k)^{j-1}p(1-p)^{k-1}}{p(1-p)^{k-1}}=\frac{p}{k}(1-\frac{p}{k})^{j-1}$$

I understand why $P(T_1=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$, but how does $P(T_1=k)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty (\frac{p}{k})(1-\frac{p}{k})^{j-1}p(1-p)^{k-1}=p(1-p)^{k-1}$?

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{p}{k}\right)\left(1-\frac{p}{k}\right)^{j-1} p(1-p)^{k-1} = p(1-p)^{k-1}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{p}{k}\right) \left(1-\frac{p}{k}\right)^{j-1}$$

Comment: I am not sure if your question is relevant to the original question. The equation you typed in the question line is essentially $\Pr\{T_1 = k\} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\Pr\{T_1 = k, T_2 = j\} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\Pr\{T_1 = k\} \Pr\{T_2 = j|T_1 = k\}$ which is just the law of total probability. You do not need these in this question; you only need to know that if $T_1 \sim \text{Geo}(p)$, then $E[T_1] = 1/p$. Note the first line should correct to $T_2|T_1 = k \sim \text{Geo}(p/k)$, and the second line should be $E[T] = E[T_1] + E[E[T_2|T_1]]$, and then plug in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've confused things with clutter.   Keep it clean.

We know $T_1 \sim  \mathcal{Geo}_1(p)$ so $\mathsf E(T_1) = 1/p$

We know $T_2\mid T_1{=}k~\sim~\mathcal{Geo}_1(p/k)$ so $\mathsf E(T_2\mid T_1)= T_1/p$

Finally we just use the **Law of Iterated Expectation** to put it together:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(T) =&~ \mathsf E\big(\mathsf E(T_1+T_2\mid T_1)\big)\\ =&~ \mathsf E(T_1)+\mathsf E(\mathsf E(T_2\mid T_1)) \\ =&~ 1/p+1/p^2\end{align}$$

That is all.